# Why do we need the Markovian property in Markov chains Monte Carlo?

Tags: references, stochastic-processes, markov-process, monte-carlo

Adaptive Markov Chains Monte Carlo (MCMC), unlike traditional MCMC methods that rely on fixed proposal distributions, dynamically adjust their proposal distribution based on the information gathered during the sampling process. This adaptivity aims to improve the exploration of the state space (shorter mixing time), leading to faster convergence to the target probability distribution.

Because of the proposal distribution optimization happening during the sampling, these chains are usually **not** Markovian. Under certain assumptions (**Diminishing Adaptation** and **Containment** [1]) these chains are proven to be **ergodic** and the **weak law of large numbers** holds:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i)}{n} \rightarrow \pi(g)=\int g(x)\pi(dx) \qquad  for \qquad n \rightarrow \infty$$

where $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ is a Markov chain samples sequence, $\pi$ is the target probability distribution, $g$ is a function $g:\chi \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\chi$ is the state space.

My questions are:

1. Is **ergodicity**, together with **reversibility** (the chain satisfies the **detailed balance** condition), sufficient conditions to ensure the convergence of the chain to the desired target probability distribution (the one satisfying the detailed balance), even if the chain is **not** Markovian?
2. If the answer to the first question is yes, then why do we need the Markov property in MCMC? Is it a desirable property simply because it makes the theoretical analysis of MCMC easier? Or does it have any other purpose?

[1] *G.O. Roberts and J.S. Rosenthal. Coupling and ergodicity of adaptive Markov chain Monte Carlo algorithms. Journal of Applied Probability, 2007.*

Comment: The [journal paper you cite](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27595854) is available from JSTOR (registration required to view 100 papers per month).  The authors say in the abstract that they give "counterexamples to demonstrate that the assumptions we make are not redundant."   Have you considered those examples in the light of your concerns about convergence "to the desired target probability distribution"?